# Directory.GetDirectories on a certain server changes non-english characters to english ones.. why?

Tags: c#

The problem is in the topic. `Directory.GetDirectories` changes all polish characters to
english ones..

For instance: ą -> a, ć -> c, ....

How to make it to return the right characters?

Thanks

**Edit**

```
var list = Directory.GetDirectories(directorySource);
Console.WriteLine(list[0]);
```

Under debug it returns the right signs, on server 2008 without non-english letters ...

Comment: What happens if you view these paths in the explorer? Does it show the right chars?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Could you provide a short, complete program that demonstrates this along with some details about your execution environment?

Comment: @nvoigt yep, in explorer there is the right letter

Comment: What language packs are installed on each installation of Windows?  What version of Windows?  What version of the .NET Framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It was the wrong language for non Unicode program set in the system. Changed to polish, It solves the problem.